How to Set Ubuntu as the Default Boot Option to Avoid Pressing F12 at Startup
Whenever I log into my computer, I always have to press F12 to access the one-time boot menu and select the Ubuntu option. I only have Ubuntu installed as the operating system. If I forget to press F12, I get a blank screen, and if I press any key on the keyboard, it gives a beep sound. How can I fix this so that my computer automatically boots into Ubuntu without needing to press F12?

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you get inside the UEFI setup and tell us about the boot options in there?

Your BIOS start up is set wrong. Put the USB boot media in and I bet it starts. Your forgot to set it back to hard drive after the install?

Normally grub uses efibootmgr to change UEFI boot order. see man efibootmgr and -o parameter, But a few computers like HP revert to default boot "Windows Boot Manager" You may be able to change boot order in UEFI settings (not one time boot menu) and boot tab of defaults. Or you can create a Windows entry that boots Ubuntu.See IV. But only recommended if not booting Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

I am using Ubuntu version 18.04
